# Nested Looping for Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I've just learn Delphi 7 and need to make a nested loop with the following output :

```
5
5 4
5 4 3
5 4 3 2
5 4 3 2 1
```

To do that I use this code

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var a, b : integer;
begin
  for a := 5 downto 1 do
  begin
    for b := 5 downto a do
    begin
      label1.caption := label1.caption + inttostr(b);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The best I can got is 554543543254321.
I've tried to include #13#10 in the label1.caption to make a new line but it turn into this :

```
5
5
4
5
4
3
5
4
3
2
5
4
3
2
1
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  You question would likely get a much better reception if you include the code you are writing.  After all, readers here cannot see your screen, aren't telepathic and are understandably reluctant to spend their time guessing what the problem might be when you could save them the trouble of guessing.  After all, you said yourself you are a Delphi novice, so what you are doing wrong could be almost anything.  That's why @SimoneNigro said to post your code.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've edit my post to include the code now. Thanks for welcoming me and the reminder :)

Comment: Don't use a `TLabel`. Use a `TMemo`, and add each line with `Memo1.Lines.Add`.

Comment: @Ken Using a label is perfectly ok.

Comment: @Tom: A TLabel is not (for most uses) appropriate for displaying multi-line text. The code (as posted) will not display multiple lines. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: Add the newline in the outer loop

Comment: @Ken OP's problem is not due to using `TLabel` as I'm sure you know. The code, properly corrected, can show the result in a label, just as well as in a `TMemo`.

Comment: @Tom: Yes, I'm aware. Using a proper multi-line control can help with debugging, as it eliminates the display issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the #13#10 in the outer loop, not the inner one, i.e.:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var a, b : integer;
begin
  for a := 5 downto 1 do
  begin
    for b := 5 downto a do
    begin
      label1.caption := label1.caption + inttostr(b);
    end;
    label1.caption := label1.caption + '#13#10';
  end;
end;
```